# Click on "Show more deals" in webpage with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, lazy-loading, webdriverwait

I'd like to click on every 'Show 10 more deals' on the following page: "https://www.uswitch.com/broadband/compare/deals_and_offers/" but it does not seem to work.
I'm stuck having the following error:

```
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element'
```

My code is the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://www.uswitch.com/broadband/compare/deals_and_offers/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\temp\chromedriver.exe')

browser = driver.get(url)
while True:
    button = WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Show 10 more deals')))
button.click()
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Show 10 more deals** on the page `https://www.uswitch.com/broadband/compare/deals_and_offers/` you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

  url = "https://www.uswitch.com/broadband/compare/deals_and_offers/"
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  browser.get(url)
  while True:
      try:
          browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='us-btn us-btn--action' and contains(.,'Show 10 more deals')]"))))
          browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.us-btn.us-btn--action[name='visible_products']"))))
          print("Button clicked")
      except:
          print("No more Buttons")
          break
  browser.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Button clicked
  Button clicked
  Button clicked
  Button clicked
  Button clicked
  Button clicked
  Button clicked
  Button clicked
  Button clicked
  Button clicked
  No more Buttons
  ```

Comment: Thank you. I do get the following error eventually:

WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <button class="us-btn us-btn--action" name="visible_products" value="53" data-event="true" data-event-category="Responsive Compare" data-event-action="Show 10 more products" data-event-label="Show 10 more products" data-event-value="43">...</button> is not clickable at point (981, 920). Other element would receive the click: <div class="us-loader__overlay"></div>

Comment: @sammtt Check out my updated answer and let me know the status

Answer (score 0):

Try the following which uses a CSS attribute = value selector to target the `data-event-action` attribute of the button by its value

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-event-action="Show 10 more products"]').click()
```

Replace `driver` with `browser` if required.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
while not re.search(r"Showing (\d+) of \1 ", browser.page_source):
  browser.execute_script("document.querySelector('[data-event-label=\"Show 10 more products\"]').click()")
  time.sleep(1)
```

This avoids the selenium errors that will eventually drive you nuts.